# carousel indicators dot1 display none on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a carousel and it is working quite good but when I click on any dots, the dot1 disappear. I checked its css and it comes to my knowledge that when I click any dot, dot1 gets css display:none from somewhere.

this is my code for dots.

```
 <ol class="dotss carousel-indicators" style="margin-top: 20px;z-index: 0;">
              <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="abc active"  id="a"></li>
              <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1" class="abc" id="b"></li>
              <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2" class="abc" id="c"></li>
 </ol>
```

This code I am using to color it.

```
 $("ol li").click(function(){
var id= $(this).attr('id');

if (id == "a") {
 $("#a").css("background-color", "white");
 $("#b").css("background-color", "#247ba0");
 $("#c").css("background-color", "#247ba0");
    }
 if (id == "b") {
 $("#b").css("background-color", "white");
 $("#a").css("background-color", "#247ba0");
 $("#c").css("background-color", "#247ba0");
   }
  if (id == "c") {
   $("#c").css("background-color", "white");
   $("#a").css("background-color", "#247ba0");
   $("#b").css("background-color", "#247ba0");
 }



});
```

This is live link.
http://www.millionmilestech.com/innovision/index.html

Comment: where is carousel?

Comment: On left of page. One the left of image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.undo_comment_delete_js', function () {});
```

It might work.

Comment: How it is supposed to work? Can you explain please. what is undo_comment_delete_js??